# load part of a page with jquery/ajax/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a series of links that will load a section of another page into my main page container `#pageCont`. I am using the script below and it works perfectly, but only on the first link, the 2nd and 3rd links just redirect me to the actual pages. I am new to jquery and ajax so i don't have any idea how to go on with this code.

```js
$("#embed-uri").on("click", (function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url:$(this).attr("href"),
        success: function(response) {
            $("#pageCont").html($(response).find("#target"));
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id"pageCont" class="main">
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
<li><a id="embed-uri" href="/webpage1/"</a></li>
<li><a id="embed-uri" href="/webpage2/"</a></li>
<li><a id="embed-uri" href="/webpage3/"</a></li>
</div>
```

.

Comment: Having duplicated IDs in a single document is invalid HTML. Consider fixing that. `li`s should also be not be children of `div`s

Comment: `<a id="embed-uri" href="/webpage1/"</a>` should be `<a id="embed-uri" href="/webpage1/">item text</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use class instead of same id's like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id"pageCont" class="main">
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
<div><a class="embed-uri" href="/webpage1/"</a></div>
<div><a class="embed-uri" href="/webpage2/"</a></div>
<div><a class="embed-uri" href="/webpage3/"</a></div>
</div>

$(".embed-uri").on("click", (function(e){
$.ajax({
url:$(this).attr("href"),
success: function(response) {
$("#pageCont").html($(response).find("#target"));
}
});

e.preventDefault();
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class for an "a" tag instead of id then change the "#" selector to ".". It should work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You have trouble with your selector) Replace id with class. Like that)

```js
$(".embed-uri").on("click", (function(e){
$.ajax({
url:$(this).attr("href"),
success: function(response) {
$("#pageCont").html($(response).find("#target"));
}
});

e.preventDefault();
}));





<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id"pageCont" class="main">
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
<li><a class="embed-uri" href="/webpage1/"</a></li>
<li><a class="embed-uri" href="/webpage2/"</a></li>
<li><a class="embed-uri" href="/webpage3/"</a></li>
</div>
```